# How to properly use react markup so that the website content can display properly when sharing link on social media?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a website with react and when I share the link on social media, it appears like the following:

[image]

How to have the website preload the content when sharing the links? Should I use something other than `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`, to render the data?

**Server.js**

```
 app.get('/*',(req, res) => {

 getStore(function(err, AppStore){

if(err){
  return res.status(500).end('error')
}

match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
 // Get React markup
  const reactMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />)
  res.locals.reactMarkup = reactMarkup
  if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
  } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
  } else if (renderProps) {
      // Success!
      res.status(200).render('index.html')
  } else {
      res.status(404).render('index.html')
  }
})

})
})

app.listen(app.get('port'))
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
     <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Custom CSS -->
     <link href="/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="/css/cosmic-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Custom Fonts -->
     <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" 
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" 
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

     <title>{{ site.title }}{{# page }} | {{ page.title }}{{/ page }}</title>
</head>
<body class="hidden">
     <div id="app">{{{ reactMarkup }}}</div>
     <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```